# android edit calendar event

Tags: android, calendar

I am writing an app where I can input a date and then add it as an event to the android calendar with an intent. Inserting is no problem by using this code:

```
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, 1001);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, uri)
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, date.getTimeInMillis())
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, date.getTimeInMillis() + 7200000)
        .putExtra(Events.TITLE, R.string.calTitle)
        .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, getString(R.string.calDescription))
        .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, getString(R.string.calLocation))
        .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
startActivity(intent);
```

But when I update my date I dont want another event in my calendar but updating the old one. When I use Intent.ACTION_EDIT the calendar activity ist not even shown. Using ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT only leads to an exception...All I want is to update the initial event.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance